# What is the use of Tasklet step in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

There are 2 different types of steps in Spring Batch, either we can configure the job using a Tasklet step or a chunk oriented step. In chunk oriented step we can read, process and write data in chunks for better performance. Whilst the tasklet step reads, processes and writes the whole data at once like other traditional programs using spring boot.

How Tasklet step, differs from the traditional programs using springboot and what is the extra level of usage that the tasklet step provides?

Clear explanation of the major differences between tasklet and chunk oriented steps.

Answer (score 0):

In chunked mode, Spring will take care of calling a reader, forwarding the data to the processor and finally the writer. You can configure features like transation size, but the control is on Spring.

In Tasklet mode Spring will not impose the structure and the Tasklet can decide on it's own how to do the job. That does not mean all the data has to be read in one step.

It may come handy when Spring control is not useful. Just assume depending on the data multiple different databases need to be addressed - then Spring's transaction control would be meaningless.

If it helps, also study documentation for JSR-352 Java Batch, such as [Understanding Java Batch](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system/files/inline-files/WP102706_WLB_JSR352.002.pdf). Your question is pretty much when to use Batchlet vs Chunk based processing:

*For a batchlet your application code just gets control once and does whatever it needs to
do. A chunk step is different because it always contains a loop. The batch container will
create a loop around calls to your application. The idea is that your application will do
some limited amount of processing, perhaps on a single item of data, and then return so
the container can loop around and we do it again.*

*Obviously you could do this in a batchlet yourself, but the chunk model brings with it some
pretty fancy options that the container takes care of for you. We’ll dig into that as we work
our way through the chunk programming model. But at a high level a chunk step is simply
the container calling your application in a loop until you are done. In theory each pass
through the loop does similar processing with different data, although really that is up to
your application.*

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your answer haven't addressed my question completely. How do you think that tasklet step will provide an extra level of usage in spring batch besides springboot. 
Also, could you please throw some light on your statement above, _That does not mean all the data has to be read in one step_, do you mean we can also read data in chunks using tasklet step?

Comment: The tasklet can itself decide to implement chunks, yes. But whether or how it does, is up to the tasklet (that means you as developer). Only use it when you feel the Spring chunk pattern does not suit your need.